# Can't Import applicationContext in test class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

my applicationContext.xml,webmvc-config.xml are in WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml

when i try the following, it doesn't load, and i get `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })
```

i am using spring 3, junit 4.7.

it works with the dirty workaround by copying applicationContext.xml in resources folder, so it's duplicated.

and i changed the loading to:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/applicationContext.xml" })
```

my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

  <!-- start up and shut down Spring's root WebApplicationContext (Interface to provide configuration for a web application) -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Central dispatcher for HTTP request handlers/controllers: take an incoming URI and find the right combination of handlers (generally methods on Controller classes) 
  and views (generally JSPs) that combine to form the page or resource that's supposed to be found at that location. -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>p</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml                       
            </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>p</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/p/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- allows one to specify a character encoding for requests. 
  This is useful because current browsers typically do not set a character encoding even if specified in the HTML page or form -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!--  
  <filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class> 
  </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name> 
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  </filter-mapping>  
  -->


  <!-- Based on the popular and very useful mod_rewrite for apache, UrlRewriteFilter is a Java Web Filter for any J2EE
       compliant web application server (such as Resin or Tomcat), which allows you to rewrite URLs before they get to your
       code. It is a very powerful tool just like Apache's mod_rewrite. -->
  <filter>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name> 
  <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name> 
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

please advise a better solution.

Comment: What is your classpath location? If it is a servlet it is normally `WEB-INF/classes` that means you've to keep your applicationContext file in `WEB-INF/classes/spring/applicationContext.xml` and use the configuration as `@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml" })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, finally i was able to do it as follows (based on **spring roo** generated application):

i put my applicationContex.xml file inside the directory:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring
```

and in the web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and in the unit test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml" })
```

Answer (score 7):

The classpath of a web application is composed of

- WEB-INF/classes
- all the jars under WEB-INF/lib

So, if you want to load the context file from the classpath, you need it in one of those places. Put it in `WEB-INF/classes/spring` and load it using `classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml` for example.

EDIT: I just realized that you have a problem loading the context file from a JUnit test. The answer is similar, though. The directory containing `WEB-INF` certainly is not in the classpath of your unit test runner. The unit test runner should use more or less the same classpath as the application server, so the file should be in a location that makes it go to a JAR file or a directory that is in the classpath of the test after the build.  If using Maven, the `src/main/resources` directory is normally one of them: everything in that directory goes to the `target/classes` directory, which is in the classpath of the unit test runner.

Comment: sorry i don't understand what do you mean by putting my context in: WEB-INF/classes/spring, do you mean create a new folder in WEB-INF, or in the target/classes create a new folder called spring or what, i can't get it.

Comment: target/classes is the directory where Maven compiles the classes and copies the resources. After the compilation, your build probably generates a war file, or an exploded war file. This war file or exploded war file is what is used by the application server to run your web app. And the application server doesn't care how your sources are organized and which build tool you use to build the war. What's important is the structure of the war file, which must respect the JEE spec. So put the file where it needs to be so that, *after the build*, it is located in WEB-INF/classes/spring in the war.

Comment: If using Maven, putting it in the src/resources/spring directory should make it go to WEB-INF/classes/spring after the build. But it might depend on your pom.xml.

Comment: well, when i did that, i was able to run the test successfully, but wasn't able to run the application, i am getting following exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/resources/spring/applicationContext.xml]

Comment: I think @JB is right, You just need to add the (classpath*:context.xml) in your web.xml, that should resolve the issue, I keep my context file in resources directory to access them from my tests

Comment: That's because you load it from the classpath in your tests, and load it from a servlet context resource in your app. Either load it from the classpath everywhere, or configure your build so that it's copied to target/test-classes (to be available from the test classpath) AND to WEB-INF/spring (to be available from the app, using a servlet context resource).

Comment: @Prasanna Talakanti, how to add it, more details please ?

Comment: @JB about the first solution of load it from the classpath everywhere, how can it be done ?

Comment: Forget about it. I'm not sure it's easy. Go for the second one.

Comment: Read the maven documentation, and if you don't know, ask another question. This is not a spring question anymore, but a Meven one.

Answer (score 1):

I keep my application context files in (src/main/resources) and add the class path suffix to access them from test or web.xml

To access the context file that is located in src/main/resources from (web.xml), add this config to your web.xml

```
 <context-param>
  <description>
           Context parameters for Spring ContextLoaderListener     
      </description>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
     <listener-class>
           org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

This is how my test config looks like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public class MyTest 
{
}
```

Comment: above is done for applicationContext only or all spring configuration files like mvc-config,security,servlet.

Comment: i mean should i do the same for mvc config : <servlet>
    <servlet-name>p</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
   classpath*:webmvc-config.xml      
   </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

Comment: I do that for all them but I think it has to do with my personal preference of keeping all my configuration files in src/main/resources directory. I will leave it up to you where you want mvc/security/servlet config files though

Comment: coz when i made the similar to webmvc-config.xml  as above the application doesn't run, and i cannot find any exceptions, it builds and starts with no errors, but nothing is displayed just 404.

Comment: I have an application that works this config, just to test that it is actually finding the file instead of webmvc-config.xml give a wrong name, You should get an file not found exception. If you get that at least it proves the point that the config is not the problem. Also can you set the logging from spring to info in your log4j to get most information possible as container boots up.

Comment: when i changed the file name i didn't get any exception ?

Comment: Sorry, I did the same thing that asked you (wrong file name for application context) to do and debugged through spring code this is what i found. spring does not seem to care if the context file provided is incorrect as long as it is not null. This is what spring does it first loads the context file from listener then tries to load the dispatch servlet beans, If not found just sets the parent context (contexext loader context) on to the dipatch servlet. To get back to your problem on 404 if you are not seeing errors u'r app is booting up fine, What is the URL to the app?

Answer (score 1):

A different solution is to add the applicationContext to main/src/resources.

Also add (a second one) application context (for the servlet) to META-INF, with only one line that imports the first context from the classpath

```
  <import resource="classpath:/mypackage/my-servlet.xml"/>
```

Then you can import the first one into the test, and there are no duplicate definitions.